# Issue switching between Wifi drivers

Tags: wireless, drivers

I've been having issues with my Wifi lately, so I followed the steps [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Switching_between_drivers) and the driver `brcmsmac` seems to work perfect on my computer. Then, I blacklisted wl and b43:

```
echo "blacklist drivername" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-broadcom-wireless.conf
```

Updated initframs `sudo update-initramfs -u` and every time I restart my computer I have to do the `sudo modprobe brcmsmac` command to activate my wifi.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo su
echo brcmsmac >> /etc/modules
echo bcma >> /etc/modules
exit
```

I suspect you'll be all set.